# Do code snippets or HTML content blocks apply retroactively?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I recall my old coworker telling me that if you change a snippet - it will be refleted in emails that already use that snippet - is this true?  I just tried a test and it did NOT apply to the email holding that snippet

Is there any functionality that allows me this ability to change a "block" then have it update in many places?

Comment: are you talking about triggeredsends?

Comment: Im talking about created code snippets in contnet builder when you create a code snippet or HTML block or TEXT block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way that you can have changes to the original content block show in the email 'automatically' is if you use the 'reference block' in WYSIWYG or the ContentBlockby... AMPscript or SSJS functions.

This also does not apply to Triggered Sends as you will need to pause, republish and restart the Trigger in order for any changes to the email to take affect.

Once you drag a block into an email, it becomes a completely separate entity that is tied only to that email. Any changes made there will not be reflected in the original block (unless you use the 'save to original block' option) and vice versa.

---

**EDIT**

Here is a sample of using the AMPscript ContentBlockBy... as you requested inside of the comment. For the example I chose [ContentBlockByID](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/contentimagebyid.htm).

Inside the email:

```
%%=ContentBlockByID(12345)=%%
```

This will then pull the content inside of the block 12345:

```
Thank you for being my friend, %%=AttributeValue("fname")=%%
```

After using this (exactly as above - or the reference block in WYSIWYG) in multiple emails, you realize you used the wrong attribute name.  Now if you just used the WYSIWYG to drag this block in, you would need to go in to each email and update the block, but since you used AMPscript or Reference block, you can just go into the block 12345 and change the content:

```
Thank you for being my friend, %%=AttributeValue("FirstName")=%%
```

and this will now be reflected in each email that calls the block above.

Comment: Very interesting with ampscript - do you maybe have an example on your end of how to execute this?  I am somewhat familiar with it.

If I have an ampscript block in a code snippet - and I modify this ampscript inside that code snippet, will it apply to all emails that ahve it?

Comment: @GS65 added example code and further explanation.

Comment: So just to be clear - you have a content block with the ID 12345 and inside that content block you have the code 
"Thank you for being my friend, %%=AttributeValue("fname")=%%"

And you can basically edit this code to whatever you want and it will apply to all email's that have this content block?  

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Yes that is correct. Like I said though, in Triggers you will still need to pause publish and restart to get the new content

Answer (score 0):

I was under the same impression but I came across this help document which would lead me to believe that you would always need to republish after a triggered send has been pushed live.  Strange as my understanding was always the same as the "best answer".

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000353599&language=en_US&mode=1&type=1